# invokeRequired in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, invoke, multithreading, begininvoke, invokerequired

Is there in SilverLight something equivalent to `Control.InvokeRequired` in Winforms?

I already found that Winforms Invoke is equivalent to `Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` but I cant find nothing like `InvokeRequired`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following extension methods are very useful

```
public static bool InvokeRequired(this FrameworkElement element)
{
    return !element.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();
}
public static void Invoke(this FrameworkElement element, Action action)
{
    if (element.InvokeRequired())
    {
        using (AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                action.Invoke();
                are.Set();
            });
            are.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    else
        action.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: you can rank the answer up